# How to determine if disk is compact flash or standard hard drive

Tags: shell, ubuntu, block-device

I need to determine in a shell script if a given block device (e.g. `/dev/sda`) is a compact flash disk or a regular hard drive. Google did not help me out for once, and while `udevadm info --query=all --name=sda` gives me lots of information, theres nothing I recognize to mean "I'm definately (not) a flash drive" or "I'm definately (not) a hard drive".

Is it possible to distinguish these two types of storage devices?

I use Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I'm not sure it is - what distinction are you trying to make?

Comment: Do you mean a compact flash disk hook up as an IDE device, or just a compact flash using a USB card reader?

Comment: @pjc50 The script may run on a computer with a single CF disk, one CF and one IDE disk, or a single IDE disk, so I need to distinguish between the first and the last case since the script will have to do different things in those two cases. @penguin359 I mean a flash disk as an IDE device.

Comment: Try [`hdparm -I`](http://superuser.com/questions/221785/how-to-find-hard-disk-rpm-speed/238733#238733), which shows the rotation speed (RPM, meaningless on a CF) on some drives. Many drives don't report the info though; perhaps there's another parameter you can use.

Comment: @Gilles Bingo for `hdparm -I`, the very first line after the device name says either "_CompactFlash ATA device_" or "_ATA device, with non-removable media_". If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @lazyr: Go ahead and write the answer. I hadn't thought of the removable attribute. In fact you can get this from `/sys/block/$devicename/removable`. It'll return true for a removable hard disk, but that may be good enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems *likely* (though there may be caveats) that this will distiguish between flash-based storage devices and traditional hard disks:

```
is_compact_flash ()
{
    hdparm -I $1 | sed -n '\_Commands/features:_,\_Security:_p' | \
        grep -q CFA && return 0 || return 1
}

disk=/dev/sda
if is_compact_flash $disk; then
    echo "$disk is a compact flash disk"
else
    echo "$disk is not a compact flash disk"
fi
```

**EDIT:** Added `sed` command to guard against model or serial containing CFA.